# Chart.js - vertical line

Tags: chart.js

I want to show one vertical line. Works me only this:

```
plugins: [{
...
    afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, _, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: {
          top,
          bottom,
          left,
          right
        }
      } = chart;
...
      ctx.lineWidth = opts.width || 0;
      ctx.strokeStyle = opts.color || 'black'

     var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, 3), yaxis.top); 
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, 3), yaxis.bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
```

BUT line is hidden when the mouse is out. So how to do line still visible?

My full-test code is here: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/

Comment: The code fragment you posted doesn't seem to have any connection to mouse events. It needs debugging, so you should post a full runnable version of your code, including data and options.

Comment: My full-test code is here: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/

Comment: The problem comes from the logic of your variable `draw`. If you set `draw` to `false` no line is painted. The way in which chart.js works is that each time the chart is drawn, the canvas is erased and all elements are drawn from scratch; then your `afterDatasetsDraw` is called - if that call doesn't draw anything, there will no line shown. I can keep the line shown by commenting out the lines for `chart.corsair = {x, y, draw: false}`

Comment: Wow, amazing - it works! But now I must move with my mouse at the chart for "create" the line. Look here: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/ - I want see my line automatically.

Comment: Then initialize `draw: true` (in `afterInit`), e.g., `chart.corsair = {x: 0, y: 0, draw: true}` which amounts to completely removing the `draw` variable because it is always `true`

Comment: It not works :'(. My code: afterInit: (chart) => {
      chart.corsair = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        draw: true
      }
    }

Comment: It works if I add `draw: true` in the initialization of your current code, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sp9rjog/)

Comment: I don!t know what I must do. In my code is "draw: true" but it not works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256606/discussion-between-kikon-and-djlj).